# Ignore empty lines in Diff View Change Screen

Tags: gerrit

How to go about ignoring empty lines in the gerrit Diff View?

I have already turned the "Ignore Whitespace" to "All" in the **Diff Preferences** but I would like to hide added or removed empty lines in the Side by Side new change screen:

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Why do you want to ignore them? Adding a line (what is shown above) is a change to the code - every diff tool will show you that. Imagine adding 100 empty lines - would you accept such code as a reviewer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in Gerrit.

Everything about Gerrit's diff screen that can be customized is listed [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-review-ui.html#diff-preferences), nothing about empty lines is mentioned. Neither is it anywhere else in the settings.

---

I thought it might be possible if you were to edit Gerrit's diff script, but from the looks of it that is not a viable way either. If you search for "git diff ignore empty lines" you'll find about zero useful hits.

There is however [this unofficial project](https://github.com/git/git/commit/36617af7ed594d1928554356d809bd611c642dd2?utm_source=anzwix) that makes it possible to ignore empty lines *that are not close to important changes*, so even if you were to somehow edit the way Gerrit handles diffs, that wouldn't really do what you want.

Comment: Thanks. The "unofficial project" would still be an improvement if I knew how to go about changing the diff used by gerrit